# "Minor edit" capability on own questions/answers

Tags: feature-request

Any edit of one's own post, no matter how trivial, has the effect of pushing the question to the top of the activity stream on the front page.  Would it be worthwhile to add the ability for a user to declare an edit to their own contribution to be minor (e.g. correcting your to you're) and this would have the effect of not pushing it back up the ladder since nothing of substance was added or removed?

Comment: I will try to have a more thorough answer to this later this weekend, but the short version is: this has been brought up before and we (that is, Stack Exchange) have always declined it. Edits shouldn't be made *unless* they're substantive; minor grammatical edits don't substantially help the question, so unless there are multiple things needing fixing, it's best to avoid them. There's also the "ninja-edit" window for this reason (questions are editable without triggering the edit history within the first 5 minutes of posting).

Comment: Okay.  I searched for the term "minor edit" here before posting so if it's already asked and answered elsewhere on SE feel free to spike this :)

Comment: No worries! It wasn't here, it was on [the network meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) but I don't recommend searching that :P It's a little too ginormous for searching well. I have the question bookmarked somewhere, but I'm currently more focused on the blizzard here in NY, haha! Promise, I'll have a more complete answer up by this weekend.

Comment: Good answers normally out power the weaker ones from the people who bump in the long wrong. It's not really a problem to be honest.